How do I draw a cone with a generatrix?
How can I draw such an image like this?

Here's the code I tried, but it doesn't seem right:
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{130} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale=2]

\filldraw[fill=green!30] (0,0,0) circle (1);

\foreach \angle in {0,15,...,360}
{
    \draw (0,0,-1) -- (\angle:1);
    
}

\node at (0,0,0) [below] {};


\foreach \x in {-1}
{
    \draw (-\x,-1,-1) -- (-\x,1,-1);
    \draw (-1,-\x,-1) -- (1,-\x,-1);
    \draw (1,\x,-1) -- (1,\x,0);
}

\draw[] (0,1,-1) -- (0,1.05,-1); 
\node at (0,1.1,-1) {\scriptsize 0};
\draw[] (1,1,-1) -- (1,1.05,-1); 
\node at (1,1.1,-1) {\scriptsize -1}; 
\draw[] (-1,1,-1) -- (-1,1.05,-1);
\node at (-1,1.1,-1) {\scriptsize 1}; 

\draw[] (1,0,-1) -- (1.05,0,-1); 
\node at (1.15,0,-1) {\scriptsize 0}; 
\draw[] (1,-1,-1) -- (1.05,-1,-1); 
\node at (1.15,-1,-1) {\scriptsize 1}; 
\draw[] (1,1,-1) -- (1.05,1,-1); 
\node at (1.15,1,-1) {\scriptsize -1}; 

\draw[] (1,-1,-1) -- (1,-1.05,-1); 
\node at (1,-1.11,-0.95) {\scriptsize 0}; 
\draw[] (1,-1,-0.5) -- (1,-1.05,-0.5); 
\node at (1,-1.11,-0.5) {\scriptsize 1}; 
\draw[] (1,-1,0) -- (1,-1.05,0); 
\node at (1,-1.11,0) {\scriptsize 2}; 



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

And here is my result:

In the three-dimensional cones I painted, there was no occlusion effect.

What have you tried? You've attached tags suggesting you know the package(s) you want to use, so please have a go and post the code if you get stuck on a particular problem.

Sorry for that, it was too late yesterday and only the question was written.

So pgf/tikz doesn't actually know anything about 3d. It works in 2d. So you either have to draw things in the right order (if at least the top things are opaque) or you have to clip or fill over things which are lower. So, in this case, you can probably clip the hidden paths to the circle? You'll have to construct the circle twice: once to draw/fill and once to clip.

Thank you very much. I completed the drawing according to the ideas you provided.

According to the comments, Tikz cannot handle 3D situations, so it is necessary to draw the figure in sections according to the perspective relationship.
Thanks to cfr
Here is my code:
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{130} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale=2]



\foreach \angle in {110,120,...,310}
{
    \draw (0,0,-1) -- (\angle:1);
    
}

\node at (0,0,0) [below] {};

% \foreach \angle in {-40,-50,...,-100}
% {
%     \draw (0,0,-1) -- (\angle:1);
    
% }

\fill[gray!0] (0,0,-1) -- (-30:1) arc (-30:100:1) -- (0,0,-1) ;
\foreach \angle in {-25,-15,...,105}
{
    \draw (0,0,-1) -- (\angle:1);
    
}
\draw[] (0,0,0) circle (1);

\foreach \x in {-1}
{
    \draw (-\x,-1,-1) -- (-\x,1,-1);
    \draw (-1,-\x,-1) -- (1,-\x,-1);
    \draw (1,\x,-1) -- (1,\x,0);
}

\draw[] (0,1,-1) -- (0,1.05,-1); 
\node at (0,1.1,-1) {\scriptsize 0};
\draw[] (1,1,-1) -- (1,1.05,-1); 
\node at (1,1.1,-1) {\scriptsize -1}; 
\draw[] (-1,1,-1) -- (-1,1.05,-1);
\node at (-1,1.1,-1) {\scriptsize 1}; 

\draw[] (1,0,-1) -- (1.05,0,-1); 
\node at (1.15,0,-1) {\scriptsize 0}; 
\draw[] (1,-1,-1) -- (1.05,-1,-1); 
\node at (1.15,-1,-1) {\scriptsize 1}; 
\draw[] (1,1,-1) -- (1.05,1,-1); 
\node at (1.15,1,-1) {\scriptsize -1}; 

\draw[] (1,-1,-1) -- (1,-1.05,-1); 
\node at (1,-1.11,-0.95) {\scriptsize 0}; 
\draw[] (1,-1,-0.5) -- (1,-1.05,-0.5); 
\node at (1,-1.11,-0.5) {\scriptsize 1}; 
\draw[] (1,-1,0) -- (1,-1.05,0); 
\node at (1,-1.11,0) {\scriptsize 2}; 

% \filldraw[fill=blue!50, draw=black] (0,0,0) circle (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

And here is the result:


Very neat! You could just use white rather than mixing 0% gray with 100% white ;). Ah, you reduced the angle between the lines. I wondered why yours looked better than mine.

I adjusted the angle distribution of the cone generatrix.

That definitely looks better.

Since pgf doesn't actually do 3d, you either have to order things correctly (with opaque things on top) or clip the things which should be 'behind'. In this case, the circle makes a good path to clip to, so it is relatively straightforward (as faking 3d in 2d goes).

\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{130} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale=2]  
  \filldraw[fill=green!30] (0,0,0) circle (1);  
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0,0) circle (1);
    \foreach \angle in {120,135,...,315}
    {
      \draw  (0,0,-1) -- (\angle:1);    
    }  
  \end{scope}
  \foreach \angle in {-30,-15,...,105}
  {
    \draw  (0,0,-1) -- (\angle:1);    
  }  
  \node at (0,0,0) [below] {};    
  \foreach \x in {-1}
  {
    \draw (-\x,-1,-1) -- (-\x,1,-1);
    \draw (-1,-\x,-1) -- (1,-\x,-1);
    \draw (1,\x,-1) -- (1,\x,0);
  }
  \draw[] (0,1,-1) -- (0,1.05,-1); 
  \node at (0,1.1,-1) {\scriptsize 0};
  \draw[] (1,1,-1) -- (1,1.05,-1); 
  \node at (1,1.1,-1) {\scriptsize -1}; 
  \draw[] (-1,1,-1) -- (-1,1.05,-1);
  \node at (-1,1.1,-1) {\scriptsize 1}; 
  
  \draw[] (1,0,-1) -- (1.05,0,-1); 
  \node at (1.15,0,-1) {\scriptsize 0}; 
  \draw[] (1,-1,-1) -- (1.05,-1,-1); 
  \node at (1.15,-1,-1) {\scriptsize 1}; 
  \draw[] (1,1,-1) -- (1.05,1,-1); 
  \node at (1.15,1,-1) {\scriptsize -1}; 
  
  \draw[] (1,-1,-1) -- (1,-1.05,-1); 
  \node at (1,-1.11,-0.95) {\scriptsize 0}; 
  \draw[] (1,-1,-0.5) -- (1,-1.05,-0.5); 
  \node at (1,-1.11,-0.5) {\scriptsize 1}; 
  \draw[] (1,-1,0) -- (1,-1.05,0); 
  \node at (1,-1.11,0) {\scriptsize 2}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

